# Flutter FutureBuilder: How to show data as Text

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter Futures. I would like to get a number from an API and then show that in Flutter:

```
        FutureBuilder(
          future: http.get('http://match.palm.pink/v1/count'),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
            else 
              return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
          }
```

However, the Flutter app shows

```
Result: Instance of 'Response'
```

I'm just retrieving a number and don't want to make a class to convert that number to. Should I use `FutureBuilder` or go with a `Future<whatever> method async { var output = await http.get(url) }` technique?

Comment: What is the output is that `get` request? A json file? Just a number? That could useful to help you.

Comment: The data is here: http://match.palm.pink/v1/count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by accessing body of snapshot.data as follows:

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: http.get('http://match.palm.pink/v1/count'),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        else 
            return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data.body}');
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If that url return a JSON file you can acces via `${snapshot.data['key']}`

Answer (score 0):

```
    FutureBuilder(
      future: http.get('http://192.168.1.2:3000/v1/count'),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        if(snapshot.hasData)
          return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data['Yourkey']}');
      }
```

You need to provide your key from firebase collection which points to your data